# App crashes after arc4random() with timer?

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, arc4random

In **Swift**, I have a timer. Every one second, the dot on the screen changes to a different dot image. It picks the dot that shows randomly. That is what I want. The app crashes right when it is launched. Like, immediately. How is this crashing fixed? And also, after that, will it work with my current code? After commenting out some stuff, and testing, the line that is causing it is `imageNumber = Int(arc4random())%13`
. How is this fixed?

**My code is as follows:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var dotChangingTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("changeDot"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    var theRandomImages: UIImage[] = [dotOne, dotTwo, dotThree, dotFour, dotFive, dotSix, dotSeven, dotEight, dotNine, dotTen, dotEleven, dotTwelve, dotThirteen]

    openingScreenDynamicDot = theRandomImages[Int(imageNumber)]
    let finalChangingDotWelcomePage = UIImageView(image: openingScreenDynamicDot)
    finalChangingDotWelcomePage.frame = CGRectMake(110, 234, 100, 100)
}
func changeDot() {
    println("the images should be changing...")
    imageNumber = Int(arc4random())%13

    var theRandomImages: UIImage[] = [dotOne, dotTwo, dotThree, dotFour, dotFive, dotSix, dotSeven, dotEight, dotNine, dotTen, dotEleven, dotTwelve, dotThirteen]

    openingScreenDynamicDot = theRandomImages[(imageNumber)]
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger show to be the nature of the crash?

Comment: Also, define your image array first and use the count as your modulo operand! That bare `13` is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting those crashes because you're trying to cast a `UInt32` value to `Int`, without regards to checking the range. Since `UInt32` is unsigned, half of the possible return values to `arc4random()` will be outside the range of `Int`, and you'll get a runtime error when you attempt the cast. The safe way to do what you're doing is to take the modulo sum first, then cast to `Int`:

```
imageNumber = Int(arc4random() % 13)
```

However, this introduces modulo bias, which impacts the randomness of the result, so you'd be better off with:

```
imageNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(13))
```

Both of these methods will give you random values between 0 and 12, inclusive.

Comment: Option 2 fixes the crashes. Although, it still does not change the image every second. What is wrong with my code causing that not to work?

Comment: Add a `println(imageNumber)` after you generate it. Random doesn't mean nonrepeating - it's not uncommon to have several of the same numbers in a row if you wait long enough.

Comment: you can skip one if you get a repeat

Comment: Still doesn't change with `func changeDot() {
        println("the images should be changing...")
        var theRandomImages: UIImage[] = [dotOne, dotTwo, dotThree, dotFour, dotFive, dotSix, dotSeven, dotEight, dotNine, dotTen, dotEleven, dotTwelve, dotThirteen]
        imageNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(13))
        openingScreenDynamicDot = theRandomImages[(imageNumber)]
    }`
@NateCook

Comment: You'd need to update your `UIImageView` with the new image, and I don't see where in `viewDidLoad()` that you added the `UIImageView` to your view controller's view hierarchy.

Comment: I made the UIImageView in my viewDidLoad, how can I access it as if it is global @NateCook

Comment: Declaring it inside your class definition, but outside any method, will make it an instance variable, or stored property - you can [read more here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Properties.html).

Comment: Declare it like this: `var finalChangingDotWelcomePage: UIImageView!` and set it up just as you are in `viewDidLoad()` (but remove the `let`). Then call `self.view.addSubview(finalChangingDotWelcomePage)`.

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar mysterious crashes with arc4random() and resolved it by switching to arc4random_uniform().

Try this:

```
imageNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(13))
```

Comment: Still getting the crashes.

Comment: yeah this wouldn't fix the issue if the algorithm was correct otherwise, what this does is actually produce a uniform distribution (if you can target 10.whatever, 10.7 i think)